# Cannot login with requests post

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

data = "memberNo=&url=&cyberId={}&cyberPass={}"
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "57",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "www.sonofelicecc.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.sonofelicecc.com",
    "Referer": "https://www.sonofelicecc.com/login.dp/dmparse.dm",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36",
}

main_headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Host": "www.sonofelicecc.com",
    "Referer": "https://www.sonofelicecc.com/login.dp/dmparse.dm",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36",
}

login_req = session.post("https://www.sonofelicecc.com/doLogin.dp/dmparse.dm", headers=headers, data=data)
main_resp = session.get("https://www.sonofelicecc.com/main.dp/dmparse.dm", headers=main_headers)

if main_resp.text.find(username) != -1:
    print("login success")
```

I am trying to login with requests without selenium. I've first tried login with selenium; however it was too slow; thus, I saved the selenium's cookie and return it to requests for faster work.
Then, I want to make all working with only requests. I've loaded all the headers correctly, but it doesn't work at all. How can I?

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", that tells us nothing about the actual problem.  Instead, tell us what the code actually does, and explain how that is different from what you wanted.

Comment: the login is not successful

Comment: "not successful" doesn't tell us any more than "it doesn't work".  **how** is it unsuccessful, exactly?  Do you get a response that the username/password is incorrect?  Do you get an error?  We need **details**.

Comment: `data = "memberNo=&url=&cyberId={}&cyberPass={}"` I believe the `data` argument is supposed to be a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: data = {
    "memberNo": "",
    "url": "",
    "cyberId": ID,
    "cyberPass": PW
}
I've changed the string data into dictionary; however it returns the same result likewise. "Not logined"